# Can I "echo" a .jpg image through php without processing it?

Tags: php

Imagine the following:

```
<img src="/image.php?image=5.jpg" />
```

Now, in `image.php`:

```
header('content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['image']);
imagejpeg($image,NULL,100);
```

This works, but this way the script loads the image, processes it, then echoes it. Can this be done without processing the image?

The reason why I want to do it this way is that I don't want people to know where the images are located, therefore I don't want to write the full path into the `img` src attribute.

I just need to send raw images to the browser, but without revealing their true location.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just [`readfile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) instead of `imagecreatefromXXX`+`imagejpeg`.

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$src = /* process $_GET['image'] to recover the path */;
readfile($src);
```

The `/* process $_GET['images'] to recover the path */` part implies any sanitizing you need to do on the input to avoid that someone requests a forbidden file. If your script input is a file path, this may mean checking from a predefined list, stripping of possible directory separators, checking against a regex, etc. Another way would be to store paths inside a database and pass the script a simple id, and recover the file path with it. This might be a better idea, as users will see no mention of any file path on the script URL (if you just pass a path, people can actually guess where files are, and that's what you're trying to prevent).

Comment: -1 This opens a security vulnerability, and allows anyone to let your server initiate HTTP requests for no good reason.

Comment: @philag not if "process $_GET['image'] to recover the path" is done right. +1

Comment: @phihag, this was copied from OP's question and fixed seconds later to `/* process $_GET['image'] to recover the path */`. A better idea than using file names at all would be to store the paths in a database and pass the ID to the script, but that's getting painfully long to express that the function OP is looking for is `readfile`.

Comment: This is just an example Guys, your way to handle security will be coded. He just show the rightway of opening file without processing in short cut way. Your so critics :p

Answer (score 12):

Sure, using [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile). Don't forget to restrict the allowed image names. Otherwise, you'd be creating a [directory traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal) vulnerability.

```
header('content-type: image/jpeg');
$img = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-z\._\-]/', '_', $_GET['image']);
readfile($img);
```

Comment: If you want to accept a hyphen, you should escape it in the regex as well: `'/[^0-9a-z\.\-_]/'`

Comment: @Nicolás Thanks for the note, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

From the example

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```